# Can't click "Run" in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Why won't it let me click the build button in Xcode?

[image: Link to picture]

Comment: Someone answer please!!!

Answer (score 2):

Restart Xcode.

See, right next to your scheme name, it says "My Mac....". If it's an iOS project, you've simply encountered a bug in xcode. Restarting is the work-around.